# Phase Wrap - Matlab Bode Plot

Tags: matlab

A quick question!

I am using MATLAB R2015b. While using bode plot with option 'PhaseWrapping' --> on I am getting the limit from 0 to 360 instead of convention -180 to 180. I can't find anything on the net. Any answers would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

**Minimum Working Example**

```
    PP                  = bodeoptions;
    PP.Grid             = 'on';
    PP.XLabel.FontSize  = 12;
    PP.YLabel.FontSize  = 12;
    PP.Title.FontSize   = 12;
    PP.Xlim             = [1e-3 1e3];
    PP.PhaseWrapping    = 'on';

    s = tf('s');
    temp = 1/s;

    bode(temp,PP);
```

What this should give me is a phase of **-90** but it gives me **270**.

Comment: I don't think that's supposed to happen. Can you edit your question to provide runnable example code so we can try to replicate this?

Comment: @horchler hey i included an edit... thanks for showing interest :)

Comment: Anyone can help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Bode plots have also the option of adjust phase offsets. You can either find the option in the right-click menu--> `Properties...`--> `Options` or adjust it via

```
PP.PhaseMatching = 'on'
PP.PhaseMatchingFreq = 1
PP.PhaseMatchingValue = -90
```

In 2016b MWE shows -90 by default though.